# How to pass an Array to a Function in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in this format:

> 'C0002','C0003','C0006','C0033','C0071','C0062','C0070 ','C0031
>   ','C0091','C0072','C0069
>   ','C0067','C0030','C0029','C0085','C0026','C0088','C0057
>   ','C0087','C0016','C0082','C0079','C0077','C0008','C0075','C0042
>   ','C0066','C0011 ','C0065','C0010 ','C0063','C0058','C0060
>   ','C0055','C0044','C0049','C0050','C0061','C0048','C0045','C0043','C0064
>   ','C0041','C0037','C0034','C0022','C0095','C0094','C0092','C0093','C0096','MFB/C0097','C0098'

Below is the PHP code:

```
$tmpy = '';
foreach($mid as $items){
  $tmpy .= "'".$items[0]."',";

}
$tmps = rtrim($tmpy, ',');
```

I tried to pass it into a function by doing the following:

```
function iheader(){
    global $mysqli,$en,$tmps;


    return $tmps;
}
```

But nothing was returned.

How can I pass this array?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: `function iheader($mysqli, $en, $anArray)` call it `iheader($your_db, $en_whateveritis, $tmps)`. Get rid of global, pass everything as parameter into the function,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would pass variables like this:

```
function iheader($tmps){
    global $mysqli,$en;


    return $tmps;
}
```

Not exactly sure where the other variables come from (`$mysql`, `$en`), but you should do it in the same way, like so:

```
function iheader($tmps, $mysqli, $en) {
    // Your code/logic here
    return $tmps;
}
```

Using  `global` is a bad practice and should be avoided whenever possible, otherwise you might soon loose track of them.

Take a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php to learn about the general syntax and the functionality.

Comment: when I tried to echo 'iheader($tmps);' at the top of my page I have **Notice: Undefined variable: tmps in**. The function was written at the bottom of my page.

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to declare `$tmps` before calling `iheader(...)`